# Scaling Samples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was taking the udemy course "Deep Learning A-Z™: Hands-On Artificial Neural Networks" and in the first homework (Build the ANN) I run the following code

```
# Import the libraries
# Opensource computation numbers GPU enabled
# import Theano as th
# import Tensorflow as tf
# import Keras as ke

# Part 1 Data preprocessing

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Get the data set
dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
# Pull test sample
testset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling_Test.csv')

# Dividing the dependent and independent variable
# -1 expresses the last column (feature)
x = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Get the independent variables
testx = testset.iloc[:, 3:13].values


# Pre processing
# Concatenate the test rows
x = np.vstack((x,testx))

# Taking care of categorical variables
# Creating encoding for categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x_country = LabelEncoder()
x[:,1] = labelencoder_x_country.fit_transform(x[:,1])

labelencoder_x_gender = LabelEncoder()
x[:,2] = labelencoder_x_gender.fit_transform(x[:,2])


# Block the ANN trying to assert true value of encoding
# Create dummy variables for the non-dichotomic encoded variable
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
x = onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()

# Take care of the dummy variable in order not to have more than 2
x = x[:,1:]

prepro_testx = np.array([x[1000,:]])

x = np.delete(x, 10000, 0)

# Splitting the dataset into the training set and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, 
                                                    random_state = 0)

# Scaling the features (columns) to standardize or normalize values
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_x = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)

# Scale it 
prepro_testx = sc_x.transform(prepro_testx)

# Part 2 Making the ANN

# Importing the libraries
import keras as ke
# Start de ANN
from keras.models import Sequential
# Make the layers
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialize the ANN you can define a graph or a sequence of layers
# Create classifier
# Classifier is the model of the neural network
classifier = Sequential()

# Construct the layers with the input layer and first hidden layer
# The number of nodes will be the number of independent variables
# For the hidden layers, we will use the rectifier function
# For the outer layers, we will use the sigmoid function
# The output is 0 or 1 so only one node
aux = ((x[1].size + 1)/2)
# Api 2
classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', input_dim = x[1].size, units = int(aux),
                     kernel_initializer='uniform'))
# Api 1
#classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = int(aux), init = 'uniform', 
#                     activation = 'relu', input_dim = x[1].size))

# Add the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', units = int(aux),
                     kernel_initializer='uniform'))

# Add the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(activation = 'sigmoid', units = 1,
                     kernel_initializer='uniform'))

# Compiling the ANN (Applying SGD to the optimizer with adam mode)
# SGD = optimizer, Loss function = SUM(y-y`)^2->min but not in this case
# The activation is a sigmoid and not a linear regression, we use Log loss
# For two output categories use binary_crossentropy else categorical_...
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the classifier (ANN) to the Training Set
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)

new_pred = classifier.predict(prepro_testx)
new_pred = (new_pred > 0.5)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

This runs and throws a False for the prediction of the set. However, in the tutorial they don't pull from an extra csv, they just put hardcoded values in

```
new_pred = classifier.predict(sc_x.transform(np.array([[1, 0, 416, 0, 41, 10, 122189.66,2,1,0,98301.61]])))

new_pred = (new_pred > .50)
```

Both codes run and return false, however the scaled values of both `sc_x.transform(np.array([[1, 0, 416, 0, 41, 10, 122189.66,2,1,0,98301.61]]))` and `prepro_testx` vary.

Why is so?

What I do differently is:

Add a new CSV in case I'd like to add several extra samples and not just one.
Append that new CSV to the main sampling.
Encode / Scale ALL of the data so it is done the same way.
Retrieve the appended extra sample before splitting.
Classify.

What they do is:
Look at the values, hardcode and scale transform with `sc_x`

Some values are similar but others are not.
Which one's the correct one?